# Having trouble adding column 4 and empty line

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

var myArray    = new Array();
    myArray[0] = 1;
    myArray[1] = 2.218;
    myArray[2] = 33;
    myArray[3] = 114.94;
    myArray[4] = 5;
    myArray[5] = 33;
    myArray[6] = 114.980;
    myArray[7] = 5;

    var myTable= "<table><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'>Col Head 1</td>";
    myTable+= "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 2</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 3</td></tr>";

    myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;                   '>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>";

  for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
    myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>Number " + i + " is:</td>";
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].toFixed(3);
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td></tr>";
  }  
   myTable+="</table>";

 document.write( myTable);

//-->
</script>
```

When I try to add a fourth column I add in

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

var myArray    = new Array();
    myArray[0] = 1;
    myArray[1] = 2.218;
    myArray[2] = 33;
    myArray[3] = 114.94;
    myArray[4] = 5;
    myArray[5] = 33;
    myArray[6] = 114.980;
    myArray[7] = 5;

    var myTable= "<table><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'>Col Head 1</td>";
    myTable+= "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 2</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 3</td></tr>";
```

myTable+="Col Head 4";

```
    myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;                   '>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>";
    myTable+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>";

  for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
    myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>Number " + i + " is:</td>";
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].toFixed(3);
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td></tr>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td></tr>";
  }  
   myTable+="</table>";

 document.write( myTable);

//-->
</script>
```

But this gives me the fourth column under the first. Although I specified right align. How do I get the fourth column in? Also I tried putting in a empty line in my code. So I did the following :

```
 myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td></br>";
```

But this gave me empty lines before my heading?

In conclusion my two questions are, how do I get the fourth column and an empty line.

Comment: I am assuming you add in the fourth column after the table is displayed. Why not just add the DOM elements?

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused. so where would I add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing out your table row in the third column, which is likely causing formatting issues.

```
myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;                   '>---------------</td>";
myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>";
myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>**</tr>**";
myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>";
```

Take a look at the third line in the above code. Get rid of the `</tr>`

Do the same for the fourth line of your for loop, and see if that fixes things.